# Is embedding a Facebook Page as complicated as it seems?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My organization has a Facebook **Page** that we would like to embed in our website.

It appears the only way to do that is via the Page Plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin).

The only way to create the Page Plugin is to use an app ID.

In order to create an app ID, I need to go through some steps on my *personal* account - which includes verifying my account with my phone number or credit card - neither of which I particularly want to give to Facebook.

Is it really this complicated or am I missing something?  Why doesn't Facebook have a simply embed code like Twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to register for a developer account or create a Facebook App to use the Page Plugin on web. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#general

If you visit the Page Plugin documentation while logged out of Facebook, you will see copy-paste code to use without an AppID. ie: Open an incognito tab, navigate to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin, click 'Get Code'.

ex:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

Use this drop in code as suggested. Be sure you are testing with a real web server not local files in your browser.